# Should I be using BindingBase instead of Binding in the signature of a class that creates a Xamarin Object?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a new object from my Xamarin code like this:

```
new ArrowGrid("Group Name", new Binding(nameof(_vm.Name))));
```

and using it like this:

```
public ArrowGrid(string text1, Binding text2, string tapCommandParam) : this()
{
   this.Text1 = text1;
   this.SetBinding(ArrowGrid.Text2Property, text2);
}
```

ReSharper is suggesting that I change to BindingBase:

```
public ArrowGrid(string text1, BindingBase text2) : this()
```

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between Binding and BindingBase.  Is there any reason to change to BindingBase?

Answer (score 1):

It is similar You could choose by yourself.

The `SetBinding` method defined by `BindableObject` has an argument of type `BindingBase` from which the Binding class derives.

The following example shows how to set a binding to a property via `BindingBase`.

```
var label = new Label ();
label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding ("Name"));
```

There are other SetBinding methods defined by the `BindableObjectExtensions` class. It creates and applies a binding to a property.

The following example shows how to use the extension method to set a binding. This is a simpler `SetBinding` extension method from this class.

```
var label = new Label ();
label.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "Name");
```